# JsonSyntaxException - Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: java, android, json, gson, android-volley

First of all I know that some other users have already asked a similar question before so you might think this is an duplicated question but it's not.

I want to make a model class to parse GoogleMaps-Direction API response from JSON format to java object.

The main goal is to make a custom request object using volley library so that I can consume the web service and having the response automatically converted into a Java object.

As you can see in the following screenshot the json response is formed by three root elements. The first two are arrays, at least, as far as I know the [] symbols are used to represent an array in JSON and the third one is just a string value.

[image]

So in the model class I'm trying to do the following, declaring some attributes to represent those elements in the JSON response.

[image]

Finally I created a new android studio project to test this application. You can see the code of the custom request as well. 
[image]

However when I run the app I always get an exception that says: 
[image]

I can understand the meaning of that message but I can't completely understand why this happens. The exception message points to the line number 16 in the response. I have tried using the `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` classes getting the same result [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, GSON tries to find the geocodedWaypoints object in the JSON string and when it does, it tries to parse its value to an instance of JSONArray. But then again, JSONArray is an object itself and also expects an identifier. Hence, to use an array as a value, you ought to use the regular array type, e.g. `String[]`.

Change the GoogleMapsResponse class to:

```
public class GoogleMapsResponse {
    private GeocodedWaypoint[] geocodedWaypoints;
    private Route[] routes;
    private String status;
}
```

And create classes for all other objects:

```
public class GeocodedWaypoint {
    private String geocoderStatus;
    private boolean partialMatch;
    private String placeId;
    private String[] types;
}
```

etc.

Comment: Correct. People cannot see they mix different libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I got rid of that annoying exception once for all. But now I don't know in which cases I have to use JSONArray, JSONObject or a custom object like GeocodedWayPoints.
Could you please briefly explain to me?

Comment: JSONObject and JSONArray are part of a different library and e.g. can be used to easily create JSON strings without worrying about where to place brackets, quotes and commas.